# How to package a .exe file into a Appx

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-store-apps, packaging, windows-store

I'm trying to package my program that I have made in Visual Studio. I can't seem to package it into an Appx file using the recommended settings in Visual Studio. I am trying to add it to the windows store and I am wondering whether there is any other ways to change a .exe file into a file that is suitable for the windows store.

Thanks for any help that you have,
FBR Studios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can repackage your .exe as an .appx package. Windows 10 has the infrastructure for it called the Desktop Bridge.
You can repackage your installer either with Desktop App Converter, a free tool from Microsoft or with any of many third-party tools that repackage .exe into various formats, including .appx.

Microsoft website has a nice page about the Desktop Bridge technology, Desktop App Converter and about and third-party tools - I suggest checking it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root